# How to get selected text from other applications and keeping clipboard text at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

Iam trying to get selected text from other applications using the folowing four lines and i have not problem with this:

```
Thread.Sleep(20);
SendCtrlC(GetWindowUnderCursor());
Thread.Sleep(30);
label1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

My problem is that at the same time i want to keep clipboard text because `SendCtrlC(GetWindowUnderCursor());` changes the clipboard text, to do that i have used a variable `before` like the following code:

```
string before = ""; //use before to keep clipboard text

//keep clipboard text
IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
before = ((String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

//get selected text
Thread.Sleep(20);
SendCtrlC(GetWindowUnderCursor());
Thread.Sleep(30);
label1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();

//return clipboard text back
Clipboard.SetText(before);
```

But it doesn't keep the text and clipboard data still lose...
someone know what is the reason?

here is all of the code:

```
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor;
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly KeyboardHookListener m_KeyboardHookManager;
        private readonly MouseHookListener m_MouseHookManager;
        private bool ctrlHeld;
        string pressedKey;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_KeyboardHookManager = new KeyboardHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
            m_KeyboardHookManager.Enabled = true;
            m_KeyboardHookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
            m_KeyboardHookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;

            m_MouseHookManager = new MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
            m_MouseHookManager.Enabled = true;
            m_MouseHookManager.MouseDown += HookManager_MouseDown;
            m_MouseHookManager.MouseUp += HookManager_MouseUp;

        }

        private void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            pressedKey = e.KeyCode + "";
            if (pressedKey == "LControlKey")
            {
                ctrlHeld = true;
            }
        }

        private void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            pressedKey = e.KeyCode + "";
            if (pressedKey == "LControlKey")
            {
                ctrlHeld = false;
            }
        }

        private void HookManager_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && (ctrlHeld))
            {
                string before = "";

                IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                    before = ((String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

                Thread.Sleep(20);
                SendCtrlC(GetWindowUnderCursor());
                Thread.Sleep(30);
                label1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();

                Clipboard.SetText(before);

            }
        }


        private void HookManager_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point lpPoint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);

        public static IntPtr GetWindowUnderCursor()
        {
            Point ptCursor = new Point();

            if (!(Form1.GetCursorPos(out ptCursor)))
                return IntPtr.Zero;

            return WindowFromPoint(ptCursor);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static public extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

        private void SendCtrlC(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
            byte VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0);
            keybd_event(0x43, 0, 0, 0); //Send the C key (43 is "C")
            keybd_event(0x43, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);// 'Left Control Up

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the _Clipboard data_ updates to a new value?

Comment: you mean the value of selected text?

Comment: yes, as you've said that the clipboard data loses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get previous selcetd text
string before = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);

// Get the selected text
Thread.Sleep(20);
SendCtrlC(GetWindowUnderCursor());
Thread.Sleep(30);
label1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);

// Set the clipboard text back to the original value.
Clipboard.SetDataObject(before, false, 10, 2000);
// Clipboard.SetDataObject(string value, ignore this, try changing the clipboard a few times, the delay inbetween trying to chnage it in milliseconds);
```

Comment: thanks worked but it freezes my mouse when selecting the text

Comment: That only preserves text though. May be better to use `DataObject before = Clipboard.GetDataObject() as DataObject;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about straight path to achieve - Try this round-about route.

While sending to SendCtrlC(GetWindowUnderCursor()), why can't you try with SendCtrlC (GetWindowUnderCursor() +  + Old clipboard data)

Non-printable character - First 31 characters of ASCII can't be entered through key-board

Read old-clipboard data and concatenate

When you are reading the data, you have split using same non-printable character.